# why not hierarchy from entity to create dto?

Tags: java, jpa, hierarchy, pojo, dto

Is there any reason to do not use hierarchy from an entity/model in order to create a dto/form object which help you to hold form search fields?

This is not a big system and these approach will help us to create real dto later if it is needed.

Our models are simple POJO's with almost any logic, maybe some validation logic but that would be valid also for the DTO.

I do not make sense to create a new DTO object with all the fields.

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Date onboardingDate;

    public User() {}

    public User(String name, String email, Date onboardingDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.onboardingDate = onboardingDate;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String getEmail() { return email; }
    public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }

    public Date getOnboardingDate() { return onboardingDate; }
    public void setOnboardingDate(Date onboardingDate) { this.onboardingDate = onboardingDate; }
}
```

my DTO class, I can use it for use creation and for search purpose.

```
public class UserDTO extends User {
    private Date fromDate;
    private Date toDate;

    public Date getFromDate() { return fromDate; }
    public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) { this.fromDate = fromDate; }

    public Date getToDate() { return toDate; }
    public void setToDate(Date toDate) { this.toDate = toDate; }

    public User convertToEntity() {
        return new User(super.getName(), super.getName(), super.getOnboardingDate());
    }
}
```

Thanks fox!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a DTO will be a subset of the entity data or also contain data from other associations in sub-DTOs or directly embedded in that DTO. If the DTO extends the entity, a user of a DTO object will have the possibility to invoke a getter to access all that state.

If your DTO is really a DTO, it will only have a subset of the data, but by extending from the entity, it might happen by accident that you access data that wasn't part of the subset that was loaded.

Imagine your user entity has detailed contact and address information. For one use case, you need that data, but for another you don't. It would not make sense to expose getters/setter for state that isn't there, would it? This is why one usually creates a separate DTO class for that purpose. You can still work with the entity type if you want to persist/update data, but even for these use cases, people sometimes tend to use DTOs because the persistent state does not necessarily represent the state which can be updated in a use case. This is especially important when you have state for e.g. denormalizations in your persistent state or cross cutting concerns like statistics or audit data.

If your model is so simple and will stay this way, then just use the entity model. If in 90% of the your use cases you need all data anyway, there is nothing you can gain from using DTOs.

Considering you have the need to create a subset of the entity state for your use cases I can only recommend you not to extend from the entity model and really just model what your use case requires. Never expose accessors to state that isn't there in DTOs. That will save you hours of debugging later.

Of course you could use your DTO for filter purposes, that's what is usually called *filter by example*, but you will notice that this has certain limits and quirks, so at some point you will need a different approach.

You can make use of a library that I develop called [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) which allows you to create DTOs as interfaces. This is not only an easier way to model DTOs, but it will also perform better because it will only fetch the state really necessary for the desired representation.